# vector to const uint16_t * type

Tags: c++, modbus

I'd like to use libmodbus for my custom project. Everything works fine with predefined static values, but i cannot use modbus_write_registers function with the fourth parameter `const uint16_t *'src'` predefined dynamically.

In practice I have to convert obtained DB values to a such kind of type, do not know how.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the tools you're using? In this case, `std::vector`?

Comment: Well, I'm not the expert in c++, hope to find the right solution, still being in a test phase...

Comment: You didn't answer my question. But I suppose that's fair, seeing as I'm not answering yours...

Comment: I've read std::vector doc understanding what I needed to know as far, apparently not enough... continue to study, thanks for push

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `std::vector<uint16_t>`, you can get access to the underlying memory buffer as a pointer using `std::vector<uint16_t>::data()` (which for this example will return `uint16_t *`).

Comment: thanks for that! I'll try to follow your suggestion though I'm not expert in c++

Comment: it works, with simple:
std::vector<uint16_t> v;
than as parameter
v.data ()